# return default value or null for Task<T>

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a wrapper around Cache library and have the following method to retrieve the cached valued based on Key:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
{
    var serializedObject = await _cache.GetStringAsync(key);

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedObject);
}
```

The problem is there is nothing in cache, I receive an error from the DeserializeObject method. I'm stuck on what how to return either null or the default value of T when nothing is stored cache.

I tried:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
{
    var serializedObject = await _cache.GetStringAsync(key);

    if (serializedObject == null) return Task.CompletedTask;

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedObject);
}
```

But Task.CompletedTask cannot be converted to `Task<T>`

I tried:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
    {
        var serializedObject = await _cache.GetStringAsync(key);

        if (serializedObject == null) return Task.FromResult<T>(null);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedObject);
    }
```

But null is not a valid parameter for T.

How do I get GetAsync to return either null or the default value of T?

**Update**

I got the following to work:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
{
    var serializedObject = await _cache.GetStringAsync(key);

    return serializedObject == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedObject);
}
```

Comment: `return null;`/`return default(T);`?

Comment: No, null doesn't work either.

Comment: What is the type constraint on `T`?

Comment: there isn't one

Comment: [`default<T>` works fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FmQyiI)

Comment: By just returning default<T> for `int` how would you distinguish between a cached value of 0 and a non hit which would also return 0?

Comment: Great question, I might want to limit T to classes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have three options:

- If you do not need to support value types, add `T : class` constraint
- Add a wrapper class that lets your caller know if accessing cache was successful, or
- Add a method to construct and cache the new value on unsuccessful retrieval.

The first implementation lets your approach compile:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key) where T : class {
    var serializedObject = await _cache.GetStringAsync(key);
    if (serializedObject == null) {
        return await Task.FromResult<T>(null);
    }
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedObject);
}
```

Here is the second implementation:

```
class CacheResult<T> {
    public bool IsSuccess {get;}
    public T Value {get;}
    public CacheResult(T val, bool isSuccess) {
        Value = val;
        IsSuccess = isSuccess;
    }
}
public async Task<CacheResult<T>> GetAsync<T>(string key) {
    var serializedObject = await _cache.GetStringAsync(key);
    if (serializedObject == null) {
        return new CacheResult(default(T), false);
    }
    return new CacheResult(
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedObject)
    ,   true
    );
}
```

Here is the third implementation:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key, Func<string,T> make) {
    var serializedObject = await _cache.GetStringAsync(key);
    if (serializedObject == null) {
        var res = make(key);
        _cache.PutStringAsync(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res));
        return res;
    }
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedObject);
}
```

The caller would need to provide a "factory" delegate to the second method in order to make a new object if a cached one is not available.

Comment: Interesting approach, does this have an advantage to returning default(T) ?

Comment: @Josh Yes, it lets the caller decide if there was a cached value when a key happens to be mapped to a `default(T)` value: for example, if `T` is, say, an `int`, this approach lets you decide if `key` is mapped to zero vs. there's no value for that key. Same goes for `struct`s with all default values.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this?
`return default(T);`

Because you're returning the default value of `T`, you might as well return it synchronously.

Comment: You need to `await` `Task.FromResult`

Comment: `return default(T);` or `return await Task.FromResult<T>(default(T));` should both work, the first option is just better

Comment: @BrunoLM Yeah, returning the default value of `T` synchronously does seem to make more sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to return a Task with a nullable type. Make sure your Task `T` is assigned the *nullable* operator, like `"T?"`, and try a legit *await* call before defaulting to the default null value of T in the thread task call. The *default* value of any reference type is null. But your methods return type of `Task<T?>` must have the "?" to accept a nullable type, as well.

```
public async Task<T?> GetByIdAsync(int id)
{
    return await _context.FindAsync<T>(id) ?? default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the options are now working in **C# 10** or above especially when you have set compiler property of `treat warning as errors` which is an important prerequisite of our project. So I resolve this by following in year `2023`

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
{
    var serializedObject = await _cache.GetStringAsync(key);
    if (serializedObject == null) {
     throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(serializedObject ));
     }
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedObject);
    return result != null ? result : throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(result));
}
```

Alternatively we can also get away by declaring `Task<T?>` instead of `Task<T>` if other code / interface allows that nullable implementation.